# Typescript not letting me use parseInt

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to get the middle index of an array in integer form, but for some reason typescript doesn't let me use parseInt:

```
const splitHalfs = (numsArray: number[]) => {
  if (numsArray.length === 2) return numsArray;

  const midElement = parseInt(numsArray.length / 2);

  //Rest of the code goes here
};
```

However this doesn't show any error:

```
const splitHalfs = (numsArray: number[]) => {
  if (numsArray.length === 2) return numsArray;

  const midElement = numsArray.length / 2;

  //Rest of the code goes here
};
```

The Error I get is:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

12   const midElement = parseInt(numsArray.length / 2);
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: It can be float as well, but as suggested in the solution we can use parseFloat

Comment: Not an answer, but `Math.floor(numsArray.length / 2)` would be much more appropriate here.

Comment: @AlexWayne yes just realized that, thanks anyways. And I mistyped `parseFloat` I meant `Math.floor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Look at the `parseInt` function definition:

```
parseInt(string: string, radix?: number): number;
```

That means, it requires the first argument as a `string`. So, here comes the **first solution:**

```
const midElement = parseInt((numsArray.length / 2).toString());
```

**Solution 2:**

You can also achieve this by `not using parseInt`. You can use `Math.floor` like below:

```
const midElement = Math.floor(numsArray.length / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the fact that by getting the length of numsArray, you are actually trying to convert a number tu another number, so you could turn back "numsArray.length" to a string or just remove the "parseInt"